# My Android app closes on run, no errors in code

Tags: java, android, crash, forceclose

I'm coding a dice game as a holiday project, but I'm kinda stuck right now: there are no errors anywhere in my code, but still, the app won't start. I really don't see why. I tried cleaning project, fixing properties but nothing works. Any help would be great.

Java code:

```
package com.bdec.tritsen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NamenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_namen);
}
public void spelregels(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spelregels komen binnenkort", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void beginSpel(View v)
{
    EditText Field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam1);
    EditText Field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam2);
    EditText Field3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam3);
    EditText Field4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam4);
    EditText Field5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam5);
    EditText Field6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam6);
    EditText Field7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam7);
    EditText Field8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam8);
    EditText Field9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam9);
    EditText Field10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam10);

    String naam1 = Field1.getText().toString();
    String naam2 = Field2.getText().toString();
    String naam3 = Field3.getText().toString();
    String naam4 = Field4.getText().toString();
    String naam5 = Field5.getText().toString();
    String naam6 = Field6.getText().toString();
    String naam7 = Field7.getText().toString();
    String naam8 = Field8.getText().toString();
    String naam9 = Field9.getText().toString();
    String naam10 = Field10.getText().toString();


    }
}
```

The XML code for the buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBegin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Begin" 
    android:onClick="beginSpel"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSpelregels"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Spelregels"
    android:onClick="spelregels" />
```

Comment: Do you have it declared properly in your `manifest`?

Comment: Can you provide your logcat please?

Comment: Sure, I've uploaded it at dropbox.com/s/ejyqcg0tmelsgnx/logcat.log

Answer (score 0):

If it just won't even start and you have no errors in your code or in your logcat then you need to have it declared in your `manifest` with the `Launcher` `intent-filter`. Something like

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.bdec.tritsen.NamenActivity "
        android:label="NamenActivity " >       
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>         
    </activity>
```

If you already have this then you will need to post logcat so we can see the source of the problem.

[The manifest Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) explain pretty well what can be and what needs to be in the `manifest`